# When debugging java application in Eclipse, how do I configure it to not close the files the debugger opened?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

When I am debugging a Java application in Eclipse, I often want to see which files were opened during a debugging session. But for some Eclipse closes the files I hit. Is there a way to leave it open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should uncheck - Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > 'Reuse editor when displaying source code'.

Answer (score 0):

You could always set a bookmark on a line of code in a file you want to open later. I know it's not really an exact solution, but still better than nothing.

Comment: @pacman I don't have Eclipse on this computer, but Google reminded me that Edit --> Add bookmark should work. There's also a Bookmarks View to list all bookmarks. I also recall adding bookmarks directly to the code by right-clicking or something similar.